# How to import a MySQL database dump into a Rails 2 project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know the command in Rails 4+, it's

```
rails db < ./path/to/db_dump.sql
```

but I don't know how to do it with Rails 2.3. I know it's old, but it's all I have to work with.

I cannot use the MySQL CLI. I have to use a Rake task because the application is dockerized, so my MySQL container doesn't "know" about my rails_app_development database.

Does anyone know the Rails 2.3 command for this, if there is one?

### Things I've tried:

**1. This one i feel like has gotten me the closest**

```rb
namespace :db do
  task :import_from_source => :environment do
    Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
    Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("./file.sql"))
  end
end
```

So i basically just made a rake task. Then in docker I can run:

```
$ docker-compose run app rake db:import_from_source
```

And it appears that everything worked. In fact, I see this in my logs:

```
app_1  | -- Dump completed on 2020-07-24 6:20:02
app_1  |
app_1  |   SQL (0.7ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
```

However when I refresh the page, I still get a "mysql table dosen't exist" error

**2. This doesn't work and I'm not sure why**

First I run:

```
docker-compose run --rm app rake db:create
```

and that works, but when I go into my db container using `docker-compose run db bash` and run

```
mysql -u root -p rails_db_development < /db_dump/db_dump.sql
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'rails_db_development'
```

Even though I created it in the app container.

Comment: When asking it's important to tell us where you researched this and what you tried so we don't duplicate your work. Without that we waste time suggesting things only to be told "I already tried that." Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: @theTinMan My bad. I'm usually good about writing questions I must've blanked when writing it. I'll update it